# Spring 3, AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer, multiple servlets

Tags: spring, servlet-3.0

With Servlet 2.5 it was possible to use multiple servlets configured in the web.xml file by simple duplicating and editing the following xml tags.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is it somehow possible to create multiple servlets using Spring's AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer with Servlet 3?

I thought that returning 2 classes in getServletConfigClasses() method and 2 paths in getServletMappings() method would be enough, but that doesn't work as I expected it to.

So, is there a (simple) way to configure multiple servlets using Spring 3 and Servlet 3?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

      XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
      appContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml");

     ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
        container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");

     ServletRegistration.Dynamic anotherServlet =
        container.addServlet("anotherServlet", "com.xxx.AnotherServlet");
      anotherServlet.setLoadOnStartup(2);
      anotherServlet.addMapping("/another/*");

     ServletRegistration.Dynamic yetAnotherServlet =
        container.addServlet("yetAnotherServlet", "com.xxx.YetAnotherServlet");
      yetAnotherServlet.setLoadOnStartup(3);
      yetAnotherServlet.addMapping("/yetanother/*");

    }

 }
```

Ofcourse, You could use any of the [addServlet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) methods as per your convenience.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't even know the ServletRegistration class. Thank you!